# Class List Across Packages Dynamically

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following problem:Can Reflection be applied across packages in java? For eg:I have two packages
Package First\src Class A
Class B
Class TestReflection
Package Second\src
Class D
Class E

Now in the class TestReflection,I have written the code to get all the class names given a Package dynamically using Reflection API's. It is working only if I give the package First\src but not with Packge Second\src.Can anybody please help me with this. I need to get the class names of all the packages irrespective of where my code is written?

I have pasted my program screenshots(In both the scenarios),along with the folder path on left hand side,and console output on right hand side.Please let me know if anything else is needed.
[Same Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhqXs.png)

[Different Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBX85.png)

Comment: Please show us your code and the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: Yes Java Reflection does work across packages.

Comment: I have edited my question above with pasting my program screenshots.Kindly have a look at them...@Marvin,@ Matej Kormuth  This is my first question on this forum..Hence kindly forgive me for my mutliple edits:)

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have different packages. You have the *same* package `test` in two different *projects*. Classes in different projects by default cannot see each other and thus reflection fails.

You need to add the second project to the [build path](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm) of the first project:
[image: Adding project to Java Build Path]

Comment: @Marvin...The same problem occurs even if the package name is different(not test).This is just an example,hence I have given only two Projects(Firs,Second)..But,ultimately I need the class list from many Projects dynamically.Is there anything else that can be done..because I cannot build path for each project (since there could be many in the runtime)...I am trying to develop an application to check the coding conventions of java .Hence this is one of the requirement in it.

Comment: @PrasunaVaddi You can get all projects using Eclipse's [ResourcesPlugin](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FResourcesPlugin.html) but I think your project needs to be a plugin itself and it will obviously only work from within Eclipse. That's a different topic, though, and you might be better off with asking a new question specifically for that.

Comment: And it doesn't matter whether the packages are equal or different - reflection doesn't care. It's the different projects (more specifically: the different class paths) that's stopping it from working.

Comment: @Marvin..Thanks for your answer..I will ask a different question ina new thread for my problem:)